# How can I use git-archive to include submodules from a bare repository?

Tags: git, deployment, git-submodules, git-bare

I'm in the process of setting up a deployment script. The basic process is:

1. Push changes to a bare repository on the server
2. Then based on new tags will create a new folder for the release.
3. **Use git archive to move the files into the release directory**
4. Runs some migrations scripts and puts it live (if all is successful).

The issue is my repository contains a submodule, which doesn't get put in the archive, and therefore doesn't get put in the release directory.

I've seen [git-archive-all](https://github.com/meitar/git-archive-all.sh), but that doesn't work on a bare repository.

If its not possible, I'm considering,

1. making the repository not bare, and updating the working copy, which would allow me to use git-archive-all. Or
2. having a second bare repository of the submodule on the server, which I could get an archive from (would have to look into this to make sure I'm getting the right revision).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this python package https://github.com/Kentzo/git-archive-all. You can install it by using

```
pip install git-archive-all
```

On OSX, you can install it also using `brew install git-archive-all`

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a different git-archive-all from the one mentioned in @Brandon's answer.

Answer (score 12):

Based on answers and comments here. You can create non-bare repo and run:

```
git ls-files --recurse-submodules | tar caf ../prog.tar.gz -T-
```

- To handle files starting with hypen, use `--verbatim-files-from`
- To put files in folder inside the archive, use `--xform s:^:prog/:`

Full version:

```
git ls-files --recurse-submodules | tar caf ../prog.tar.gz --xform s:^:prog/: --verbatim-files-from -T-
```

Comment: Thanks! Version to go directly to a directory of files (bypassing tar.gz): `git ls-files --recurse-submodules | tar c -T- | tar x -C TARGET_DIR` (Effectively converts a git non-bare repo to a git-free directory)

Comment: It's worth noting that this will give the files as they exist in the (possibly dirty) worktree, rather than what's committed to a particular ref.

Comment: Note: This might behave unexpectedly with symlinks. Ex: `foo/bar -> ../baz` becomes `prog/foo/bar -> prog/../baz`

Comment: Of you are on macOS, then consider to look for solution in this SO answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/725152/205472

Answer (score 3):

If your submodule is in a repo accessible from the server, I would rather have a post-receive hook which would

- update a full non-bare repo (so a second repo beside your original bare one), including the submodule (`git submodule update --init`)
- `git archive` from that second repo (you would be sure to get the right version since the non-bare repo would reference the right version of the submodule)
  Since the non-bare repo would contain the parent repo *and* its submodules, `git archive-all` would be able to detect the `.git` subdirectories and would archive *everything*.

If the submodule isn't accessible from the server, that means:

- it needs to be pushed in its own repo on the server
- the submodule in the parent repo needs to be reference with a relative path, in order for the parent repo to still be able to retrieve said submodule once pushed on the server.

Comment: Even with submodules initialized and updated. They don't appear in an archive produced with git-archive. Hence [git-archive-all](https://github.com/meitar/git-archive-all.sh). Would there be any reason to keep both a bare and non-bare repository?

Comment: @Jacob: the submodules won't appear if their repo referenced in the `.gitsubmodules` file isn't accessible from the server. On the other point, `git archive-all` will work better on a non-bare repo (which will contain the extra `.git` subdirectories)  with all the right submodules in place than in a bare repo (without any `.git` to grep and parse).

Comment: @Jacob: that is why I recommended a non-bare repo with submodules checked out in it: `git archive-all` will detect and archive everything. I have edited my answer to add that point.

Comment: If you update a full non-bare repo (with modules updated using `git submodule update --init`), what does `git-archive-full.sh` provide that tar does not already do for you? Like `tar --exclude-vcs --exclude=.gitmodules -c .`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick: https://github.com/meitar/git-archive-all.sh/wiki

Comment: Actually, looks like it has a few small issues so it might not be ready for prime time yet.

Comment: this worked for me after changing it to use the `-o output_file` instead of `> output_file` format for `git archive`

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a different git-archive-all from the one mentioned in @ismailsunni's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is as a few-liner:

```
prefix=$(basename "$(pwd -P)")
{
  git ls-files
  git submodule foreach --recursive --quiet \
                'git ls-files --with-tree="$sha1" | sed "s#^#$path/#"'
} | sed "s#^#$prefix/#" | xargs tar -c -C.. -f "$prefix.tar.xz" --
```

Comment: Downside to this is that you can't specify a ref for the root repository :P Always runs for whatever is currently checked out.

Comment: Another problem is that if the repo (including submodules) have more files than fits on tar's command line, the archive contains only a subset of files. Solution is to use `--files-from` rather than xargs: `tar -c -C.. -f "$prefix.tar.xz" --verbatim-files-from --files-from=-`

Comment: ```git ls-files --recurse-submodules | cpio -o --format=ustar > HEAD.tar```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following after the regular archive command:
`git submodule foreach 'cd REPO_ROOT/$path && git archive HEAD | tar -x -C TARGET_ROOT/$path'`

Here the REPO_ROOT is where your repo stands and the TARGET_ROOT is where you put your archived version. (I assume that you have a TARGET_ROOT folder where the expanded version of the first `git archive` call. If you want a final zip/tar, you can tar/zip the final folder)

`git submodule foreach` provides the `$path` variable. See `git help submodule` foreach section for more details.

Comment: `git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree.` This question is regarding a bare repo.

Answer (score 0):

I my case build system relies on git to know version of source code it builds from.
To create a **very minimal archive** of full git tree **keeping git** i used

```bash
git clone --recursive --progress git@mycompany.com:myrepo --shallow-submodules --depth 1
```

*hint* *--depth is required for only super big repos with super long history or with amount of big files. in my case shallow cloning helps to reduce size of .git pack **from 2.5GB to 94MB***

then remove files from worktree except `.git`

```
cd myrepo/
fd -IH '[^(.git)]' --max-depth 1 --exec-batch rm -rf --
```

*fd could be installed via `apt install fd-find`, also can use default util `find` or bash's `extglob`*

next step compress

```
cd ..
tar cvzf myrepo.tgz myrepo/
```

---

#### uncompress

```bash
tar xf myrepo.tgz
cd myrepo
git checkout -f --recurse-submodules
```

now all worktree is in actual state.

with `--depth 1` you always will have only one branch with the only one commit.

---

#### last note

there is no possibility to clone repo bare and recursive at a time, for submodules git requires actual worktree.

`--recurse-submodules[=<pathspec>]`
After the clone is created, initialize and clone submodules within based on the provided pathspec. If no pathspec is
provided, all submodules are initialized and cloned. This option can be given multiple times for pathspecs consisting of
multiple entries. The resulting clone has submodule.active set to the provided pathspec, or "." (meaning all submodules) if
no pathspec is provided.

> Submodules are initialized and cloned using their default settings. This is equivalent to running git submodule update --init
> `--recursive <pathspec>` immediately after the clone is finished. This option is ignored if the cloned repository does not have
> a worktree/checkout (i.e. if any of `--no-checkout`/`-n`, `--bare`, or `--mirror` is given)