# Does cloning a repo by a certain HASH include snapshot of included submodules?

Tags: git, hash, branch, commit, git-submodules

I need help when cloning my **github** repo with its submodules.
I am currently using this generic command :

```
git clone --recursive ${GIT_SOURCE} -b master ${MY_DIR}
```

and it works fine.

However, I was wondering if cloning my `master` branch by HASH will include the submodules "snapshot" (i.e. their own commits corresponding to that particular `master` commit) or their updated ones if i ever make one "on the road".

Is it possible to achieve this kind of result?

Answer (score 0):

The SHA1 of a submodule repo will always be the one recorded in the [gitlink entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) of the [parent repo index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309).

However, **[you can configure a submodule to follow a branch of its own remote repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)**, which means it can be updated to its latest origin/master (if you want to follow master).

You would then need to add, after the `git clone`:

```
git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

That would update the submodules content to the last fetched SHA1 of their respective remote repos.

---

Once cloned and updated, [a program like **`git-archive-all`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5482544/6309) can generate a tarball snapshot of all the repo (including its submodules)

Comment: ok, thank you. In addition to this, is there a chance now to generate a tarball snapshot with submodules included or is this feature still missing ?