# Proper way to release in Git with submodules

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-submodules

Im starting to work with git submodules and Im a bit confused. Basically on my project I needed a modified version of hybridauth library.
So I forked hybridauth, did my changes and added it as a submodule of my repo.

Now when I try to do a release of my repo or simple download a zip copy of my master branch (I use bitbucket and sourcetree ) I get the project with an empty hybridauth folder on it.

I think I have everything configured properly. When I do changes on the submodule then I also commit then in the main repo.

But I can't download the whole project in one file to redistribute it.

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue and VonC's response worked for me as well. Just need to use `git submodule update --init --recursive` if your repo's submodules also have nested submodules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build that one archive file by:

- cloning your repo
- updating your submodules (`git submodule update --init`)
- taring the resulting work tree (or use the [`git-archive-all.sh`](https://github.com/meitar/git-archive-all.sh/blob/master/git-archive-all.sh) script I mentioned in "[How can I use `git-archive` to include submodules from a bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5482717/6309)")

However, that arcive is local only (not visible on BitBucket). [GitHub offers a way to associate an artifact (like an archive file) to a "release"](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software).

For BitBucket, you could associate your project with a [Continuous Integration (CI) service](http://www.quora.com/Which-continuous-integration-tools-support-Bitbucket), and repeat the steps above as part of a build/packaging job, and distribute the resulting deliverable (the zipped archive) through that CI service.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how Github handles releases with submodules, but for people cloning your repo, they should use `git clone --recursive git://github.com/foo/bar.git` to get your submodule.

Comment: Yep I read about that, but is not what Im really asking. In more interested on a zip file to deliver to normal users that know nothing about git